# Add To Cart Error, product redirection issue - Magento

Tags: php, magento

**Overview:**

On my product called **Test Product** has **10** quantity.

[image]

So when I put **40** quantity and press add to cart. *(Remember, the quantity of the product is 10, so it should prompt an error)*

[image]

The output is correct, the user got notified by the system that they put greater than the quantity than the actual quantity of the product.

[image]

If you look at the URL closely, before the user click the add to cart, the URL is

[image]

When the error has been shown, the URL is

[image]

Meaning, magento removes the category link and redirects to the actual product link.

**Question**
Is there any way for magento to redirect to the current category instead of the product link?

Answer (score 0):

Both redirecting to the category or the product with category included in the url is not possible by default. You need to write a module for that.

Let's have a look where the redirection is done in the code, so the behaviour can be modified.
Starting from the cart controller products are added to cart in `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()`. The product is added with

```
$cart   = $this->_getCart();
...
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

Having a closer look at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct()` the redirection url for products with insufficient stock amount is set here:

```
/**
* String we can get if prepare process has error
*/
if (is_string($result)) {
$redirectUrl = ($product->hasOptionsValidationFail())
    ? $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl(
        $product,
        array('_query' => array('startcustomization' => 1))
    )
    : $product->getProductUrl();
$this->getCheckoutSession()->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
if ($this->getCheckoutSession()->getUseNotice() === null) {
    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(true);
}
Mage::throwException($result);
}
```

The product here is loaded without the category information so the categories aren't part of this url.